# RNN implementation about time series using python

Tags: python, time-series, recurrent-neural-network, forecasting

I want to develop an RNN model with one layer and LSTM to forecasting the next day and the next 30 days. The data is from 2014 to 2019 and the head of data is in the image below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0fzH.png). I am using the daily_count column to predict the number of incidents for next day of this column.

The code to predict the next day is this:

```
train_size=int(0.8*len(data_rnn)) #80-20 split
data_train=data_rnn.iloc[:train_size,1].values
data_test=data_rnn.iloc[train_size:,1].values

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data_train = scaler.fit_transform(data_train.reshape(-1, 1))

x_training_data = []
y_training_data =[]

for i in range(30, len(data_train)): #look back=30 days 
   x_training_data.append(data_train[i-30:i, 0])

   y_training_data.append(data_train[i, 0])

x_training_data = np.array(x_training_data) #shape=(863,30)
y_training_data = np.array(y_training_data) #shape=(863,)

x_training_data = np.reshape(x_training_data, (x_training_data.shape[0], 
                                           x_training_data.shape[1], 
                                           1))

rnn = Sequential()
rnn.add(LSTM(units = 45, return_sequences = False, input_shape = 
 (x_training_data.shape[1], 1))) #45 neurons
rnn.add(Dropout(0.2))
rnn.add(Dense(units = 1))
rnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mape')
rnn.fit(x_training_data, y_training_data, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32)

unscaled_training_data =data_rnn.iloc[:train_size,1]
unscaled_test_data = data_rnn.iloc[train_size:,1]
all_data=data_rnn.iloc[:,1]

x_test_data = all_data[len(all_data) - len(data_test) - 30:].values

x_test_data = np.reshape(x_test_data, (-1, 1))
x_test_data = scaler.transform(x_test_data)

final_x_test_data = []

for i in range(30, len(x_test_data)):

    final_x_test_data.append(x_test_data[i-30:i, 0])

final_x_test_data = np.array(final_x_test_data)

final_x_test_data = np.reshape(final_x_test_data, (final_x_test_data.shape[0], 
                                           final_x_test_data.shape[1], 1))
predicts = rnn.predict(final_x_test_data) #predictions
```

Because I am new in deep learning I have some questions.

A) The above code is complete to forecasting the next day of the data or does need some additions?

B) To predict the next 30 days what I must change in the code?

C) For the same data, I have created an XGBoost model with 40 features such as the month, the day of the month, weekday, the max temperature of the day, number of incidents for previous days, etc. Can I use these in the RNN model as input to improve the performance of the model and if yes, what changes I must do in the code with a total of 40 features without the daily_count column.

D) Any advice I would appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You got to do either Autoregression or the Single-shot prediction method in order to forecast multiple steps into the future. The TensorFlow docs have some amazing explanations. Refer this https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series